# Wildcards Character in String Builder

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I am trying to create a workflow which checks if a DocID follows my naming convention, but can't seem to get wildcard characters working in the string builder.

I want something like this:

```
If Current Item:DocID equals D-* then
   perform task
```

How do I use wildcards in string builder (or is it even possible)?

Seems like a straight forward question but I can't find the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be using the 'matches regular expression' option:

```
If Current Item:DocID matches regular expression ^D-.* then
    perform task
```